# Fixed limit on the amount of documents in a mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that stores documents in mongodb, and I would like to limit the amount of documents it can store to a fixed number (say 100). Once the max number of documents is reached, storing new documents should be blocked.
I read about [capped collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/), but cannot use them due to the [limitation on deleting documents from a capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/#document-deletion).

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

in capped collection it is something like circle is you reached the limit it will override the oldest one with the new row so I recommend to use hooks specially `pre` hook to check if the collection size is 100 so you can reject the operation

Check this docs [Mongoose Hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)

Comment: That could be a solution, though I believe it requires additional access to the database. I could achieve this by calling the count() method on the collection to check if I reached the max number of documents, but I was hoping this could be done in the database level

Comment: you are right , It requires additional access to the database , I couldn't find any way to do it from database side but what are you doing right now is complex validation so I think and maybe I am wrong , that's the only way to implement complex validation

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do this via the (mongoose) schema.